# Multiple clocks on desktop

Tags: time, applet

I need to constantly check time for multiples timezones, I run kubuntu and I need to change the timezone every time to do that (or check on the web).

I couldn't find any app that could show multiples clocks for different timezones on my desktop, is there any app of this kind?

Answer (score 4):

You can use **Screenlets** clock widget  to show time with different time zone.
In the image I am using two clocks with 2 different time zone.

[image]

- First you need to install screenlets. Install it using `sudo apt-get install screenlets`.
- Now Open Screenlets manager and add two clock on the desktop.

[image]

- Now Right click on the Clock present on your desktop and goto  **properties** -> **options** -> **clocks** and set the Time Zone.
- Repeat it for other clock.

. [image]

Comment: Just checking, is this the same as https://userbase.kde.org/Plasma/Clocks ?

Answer (score 3):

You should look into Conky, you could modify it so it shows you different time zones.

```
Local: $alignr ${time %H:%M:%S}
UTC: $alignr ${utime %H:%M:%S}
CST: $alignr ${tztime /America/Chicago %H:%M:%S}
```

Would display the Local time, UTC time, and CST time.

[Here is the Ubuntu install guide!](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SettingUpConky)